# Call JSON URL using curl

Tags: json, curl, terminal

I have the following command which works great when I enter it into a browser

```
http://192.168.2.13:8092/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Addons.ExecuteAddon","params":{"addonid":"script.testscript"},"id":"1"}}
```

But I would like to call it using curl in a terminal window.  I have tried this...

```
curl http://192.168.2.13:8092/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Addons.ExecuteAddon","params":{"addonid":"script.testscript"},"id":"1"}}
```

But it is giving me the following error message..

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 52
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 67
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 75
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 45
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax for posting JSON Data with Curl**

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Addons.ExecuteAddon","params":{"addonid":"script.testscript"},"id":"1"}}' http://192.168.2.13:8092/jsonrpc?request
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra bracket at the end.

Also, you should represent the URL as URL Encoded.  Entering the data into a browser will automatically convert the URL to URL Encoded (in most cases).

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 0):

curl supports url-encoding internally with --data-urlencode:

$ curl -G -v "http://localhost:30001/data" --data-urlencode "msg=hello world"
-G is also necessary to append the data to the URL.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command